# Gridview with Client-Side Paging doesn't call OnTextChanged for Textboxes on other pages

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

I am using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) to give better client-side functionality to my ASP.NET Gridview. All is working great. This particular gridview is always in "edit mode", or is a collection of textboxes rather than string data values.

I have it so on Postback (which can only be done by clicking a Save button - everything else is done client-side), I save any records that have been marked modified. Records are marked modified by Textbox's OnTextChanged event which occurs on the postback.

Here is the problem and an example: If I modify a value on page 1, go to page 2, and then click Save...OnTextChanged only seems to get called for textboxes on page 2 so the modified value on page 1 is not saved. How can I make sure the values changed on all pages get saved when the button is finally clicked?

EDIT:
I really want to get this working. Here is the entirety of my Javascript section with Yuriy's additions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column */
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-text'] = function (oSettings, iColumn) {
   var aData = [];
   $('td:eq(' + iColumn + ') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each(function () {
   aData.push(this.value);
   });
   return aData;
}

/* Make datatables send all rows to the server for saving */
$.fn.dataTableExt.fnGetHiddenNodes = function (oSettings) {
   var anNodes = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings);
   var anDisplay = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);

   for (var i = 0; i < anDisplay.length; i++) {
      var iIndex = jQuery.inArray(anDisplay[i], anNodes);
      if (iIndex != -1) {
         anNodes.splice(iIndex, -1);
      }
    }
    return anNodes;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

   setTimeout(function () {
   $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#containers_gv").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"#top"fl>rt<"#bottom"ip><"clear">',
        "aoColumns": [
        null,
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric"}]
      });

      $('#bottom').appendTo('#gv_controls');
      $('#top').appendTo('#gv_topcontrols');


  }), 1000
});

$(function () {
  $("#containers_gv").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
});

});

function doSave() {
  var grid = $("#containers_gv");
  var hiddenRows = grid.dataTable().fnGetHiddenNodes();
  $.each(hiddenRows, function () { $(this).css("display", "none").appendTo(grid); });
  return true;
}   

</script>
```

Comment: How are you doing the paging ? is it JS or is there a postBack ?

Comment: There is no postback. It is done client-side with Datatables which uses jQuery

Comment: Are the rows of former page still in the DOM ? does it just hide them ?

Comment: Well...its a GridView at base. If I use the debugger, the Gridview has 900 some rows (the correct amount). If I use Firebug there are only one page of rows visible at a time. I don't understand why OnTextChanged only gets called for rows that are on the visible page...or how to circumvent that limitation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dataTable` plugin completely remove table rows for other pages from DOM. Since that,  textboxes from other pages except current one not forwarded to server. You can get hidden rows from dataTable's cache, add them to GridView's table and hide with `display: none` style before postback. This way their are will be accessible on server. You need to use `fnGetHiddenNodes` API function from there: [Custom API functions](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#functions)

The full script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetHiddenNodes = function (oSettings) {
          /* Note the use of a DataTables 'private' function thought the 'oApi' object */
          var anNodes = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings);
          var anDisplay = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);

          /* Remove nodes which are being displayed */
          for (var i = 0; i < anDisplay.length; i++) {
               var iIndex = jQuery.inArray(anDisplay[i], anNodes);
               if (iIndex != -1) {
                    anNodes.splice(iIndex, 1);
               }
          }

          /* Fire back the array to the caller */
          return anNodes;
     }

     $(function () {
          $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
     });

     function doSave() {
          var grid = $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
          var hiddenRows = grid.dataTable().fnGetHiddenNodes();
          $.each(hiddenRows, function () { $(this).css("display", "none").appendTo(grid); });
          return true;
     }
</script>
```

Added: `doSave` function used for Save button's `OnClientClick` proeprty: `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return doSave()" />`

Comment: First off...thanks SO much for your response. I was beginning to think I was trying to do something impossible! I am getting an error however, when I try to load the page: 'aoColumns[...]' is null or not an object. Do you know what could be causing that? I am using the 'aoColumns' parameter of the datatable.

Comment: I think this has to do with where the code snippets are arranged in the Javascript. I've tried putting everything just about everywhere I can think of and get various errors about things not being defined, etc.